# What does the colon (:) exactly stand for in Swi-Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I could not find explicitly what (:) stands for in [prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=op/3).
In interactive mode you can see the following evidence:

```
?- display(a:b).
:(a,b)
true.

?- display([a,b,c]).
.(a,.(b,.(c,[])))
true.

?- display(a:b:c:[]).
:(a,:(b,:(c,[])))
true.

?- a:b:REST = a:TAIL.
TAIL = b:REST.
```

**For what purpose (:) is introduced?** I could not find any details for it in www.
Seems that it gives another syntactic way of talking about recursive structures as Lists.

We can say that it is Right-associative, what is its priority number?

```
:-op(??, xfy, :).
```

**Is there a way to list all such kind of implicit functors?**

```
listing(op). %of course this does not work
```

Comment: In place of `display/1` better use `write_canonical/1` which is ISO.

Comment: I think the correct term is "syntax operator" and not "implicit functor". An infix op declarations for f allows writing <left> f <right> in place of f(<left>,<right>).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the [module](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=modules) qualifier, you can see its declaration with this:

```
?- current_op(X,Y,:).
X = 600,
Y = xfy.
```

Modules are an important extension to Prolog, particularly required for large programs, but miss from ISO standard. SWI-Prolog has (as usually) a pragmatic viewpoint on this, and implements an useful approach.

**OT** inspecting operators, you could find this snippet useful:

```
oplist :-
    setof((A,C,B), current_op(A,B,C), L),
    maplist(writeln, L).
```

Comment: ISO/IEC 13211-1 (Part 1) does not cover modules. However 13211-2 (Part 2) does cover modules - although this standard is very weak - that is, it leaves a lot of things implementation defined. Many claim it leaves too many things open, but then they do not conform to part 1 to begin with...

Comment: I don't quite get how this answer explains the list-like behaviour of this operator? How does the posted link to SWIProlog documentation explains the behavior of `display(a:b:c:[]).`?
In fact, I think this answer is not even relavant - where exactly on the linked page does it say that the ":" is related to "module"?

Comment: @TomCharlesZhang: in Prolog, you can use operators uninterpreted. They are just functors with fixed arity and the additional information about precedence and associativity. But what is **important**, is how that syntax is interpreted, and modules (at least in SWI-Prolog) appear on the left side of a module_name : predicate_indicator - where needed. So you can invoke a specific predicate in a module calling in that way...